# Determinar el tamaño de cada columna de un GridControl de Devexpress con C#

Tags: c#, devexpress

Traigo datos de una consulta sql, equivalen a 3 columnas pero no se como indicar el ancho de cada columna.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Si quisieras que las 3 columnas se ajustaran automáticamente al ancho del grid, puedes usar el método: [GridView.BestFitColumns()](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_BestFitColumnstopic)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la propiedad [GridColumn.Width](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_Widthtopic.aspx)

Tambien mira que valor tiene [GridOptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsView_ColumnAutoWidthtopic) porque te podria dar un resultado no esperado.

Aquí un articulo de los chicos del devexpress:
[Column Layout and Auto Width](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument649)

Answer (score 0):

es sencillo puedes establecer lo siguiente según tu necesidad

```
 GridView.BestFitColumns(); //Para que automatice
    Gridview.Columns[0].width = 100;
```

Donde `Columns[0]`, es el indice de la columna que quieres afectar.
Donde `.Width` afecta el ancho de la columna en base al indice

```
y = 100;
```

es el ancho que deseas darle a la columna...